# Declaring a value for an int as unchangeable

Tags: c#, variables, declaration

Hey I want to have something like that

```
int a=0;
a=5(be unchangeable);
a=3;
Console.WriteLine(a);//which will print 5 and not 3
```

so basically make declare the variable a number and have it be final and unchangeable, I tried looking around but I only found things that work as the int is declared and not as a new value for it is declared.

Comment: use a constant, something like: `const int a = 5;`

Comment: This has nothing to do with ints or values. It has everything to do with variables (and preventing re-assignment).

Comment: `readonly int a = 0` is always more literal to me

Comment: @jenson-button-event `readonly` only applies to Fields / Member Variables; not local variables. A slight shame, because it does have a use-case (this question being an example) :(

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this to a *local* variable?  You're writing the code, if you don't want it to change then *don't change it*.  Everything relevant to a local variable is visible locally, so there's really no excuse.

Comment: @RBarryYoung For the same reason that Scala encourages the use of `val` - to discourage side-effects because you *can't* change it. While this is a slightly contrived example, C# has no corresponding "I don't want this variable to be re-assigned" and `const` cannot be assigned a "non-const" expression which makes it very much *not* like `val`. It doesn't mean that there isn't a use-case. It just isn't supported by C#. (Java actually supports this just fine through the use of `final` modifiers on variables .. just clunky like most everything Java :D)

Comment: @pst:  Local variables, *by definition* do not have side-effects, and this behavior is much, *much* more likely to cause bugs than it is to prevent them.

Answer (score 6):

doesn't this work?

```
const int a = 5;
```

see [const(C# reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
const int a = 0;
```

> The const keyword is used to modify a declaration of a field or local
>   variable. It specifies that the value of the field or the local
>   variable is constant, which means it cannot be modified.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: But if I use const int a=0; then it doesn't at all do what i want, i want to declare the variable, and then give it another value which will be final and unchangeable and then if it gets another value then it should ignore it

Comment: Sorry. Not possible with a native type. Also, it's a silly and arbitrary requirement!

Comment: Too bad, they should add that hehe.

Comment: erm, no they shouldn't. Describe a use case where it makes sense with a native type... You could of course write your own class that mimics this behaviour...

Comment: @MitchWheat hypothetical in C#, but consider rules preventing variable use before assignment: `readonly int i; if(x) { i = a; } else { i = b; }` or, even to not be limited by const: `int a = 1; const int i = a`. (That is, I don't see why there is no `readonly` available on local variables .. except of course that the language does not support it.)

Answer (score 3):

You want the `const` keyword.

```
const int a = 5;
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The const keyword is used to modify a declaration of a field or local variable. It specifies that the value of the field or the local variable cannot be modified.

EDIT: Your requirement sounds odd and not useful. But if you really need it, you'll have to create a custom type. I'd suggest a class with a `bool` property stating whether or not it's mutable or not.

```
public class MyCustomInt
{
    public bool IsMutable { get; set; }

    private int _myInt;
    public int MyInt 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _myInt;
        } 
        set
        {
            if(IsMutable)
            {
                _myInt = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public MyCustomInt(int val)
    { 
        MyInt = val;
        IsMutable = true;
    }
}
```

Then when you use it:

```
MyCustomInt a = new MyCustomInt(0);
a.MyInt = 5;
a.IsMutable = false;
a.MyInt = 3; //Won't change here!
Console.WriteLine(a); //Prints 5 and not 3
```

That's about as good as you can get, I think.

Comment: +1 (as well other ones) - the requirement is not that uncommon for more complex objects that should become immutable at some point - your sample shows [popsicle immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different.aspx).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks, I've never heard the term Popsicle immutability before!

Comment: I don't think it is really officail term, but I like the name Eric Lippert come up with for this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

use `readonly`:

as it can be changed by the constructor but then not again.

```
public class MyClass {
 private readonly int a = 0;
 public MyClass(int a) {
  this.a = a;
 }

 public void DoSomethingWithA() {
   Console.WriteLine(this.a);
   //a = 5 // don't try this at home kids
 }
}

new MyClass(5).DoSomethingWithA();
```

[A nice comparison between](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2004/01/27/63416.aspx) `const` and `readonly`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constant with the `const` keyword.

```
const int a = 5;
```

but if you do that, you will not be allowed to change to another value.

You also can check the use of the pointers:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 3;
int *ptr1 = &x; // point to x memory address
int *ptr2 = &y; // point to y memory address

Console.WriteLine(x); // print 5
Console.WriteLine(y); // print 3

Console.WriteLine((int)ptr1); // print 5
Console.WriteLine((int)ptr2); // print 3
Console.WriteLine(*ptr1); // print 5
Console.WriteLine(*ptr2); // print 3
```

`*` char identify a pointer and `&` specify the memory address. But you should take care with pointers because unlike reference types, pointer types are not tracked by the default garbage collection mechanism.